# Assigning values to a tuple of references

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm trying to set the values of objects referred to in a tuple of references, but having trouble getting the unpacking syntax right.

```
namespace detail {

template<class... Types, std::size_t... Is>
void assign_values_helper(std::tuple<Types&...>& dest, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Types... values)
{
    std::get<Is>(dest)... = values...;
}

} // end namespace detail

template<class... Types>
void assign_values(std::tuple<Types&...>& dest, Types... values)
{
    assign_values_helper(dest, std::index_sequence_for<Types...>{}, values...);
}
```

I'm getting an error in `assign_values_helper` about `Is` being unexpanded.

Example use of `assign_values` would be

```
int a {};
double b {};
std::tuple<int&, double&> tup = {a, b};
assign_values(tup, 1, 2.0);
```

Comment: Why not use `std::make_tuple`?

Comment: @Holt How so? Note the objects being referred to don't change, only their values do.

Comment: Wrong comment edit, `std::tie` won't work because it would re-assign the tuple, but `std::make_tuple` works here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

```
tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0);
```

There are special overloaded [`operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D) for assigning different types of `std::tuple`:

```
template <class... UTypes>
tuple& operator=(const tuple<UTypes...>& u);

template <class... UTypes>
tuple& operator=(tuple<UTypes...>&& u);
```

The second one (which is the one that gets called here) does exactly what you want:

> For all `i`, assigns `std::forward<Ui>(std::get<i>(u))` to `get<i>(*this)`.

Comment: Yeah, obviously after understanding the curiosity of the syntax, favor the standard library. +1

Comment: You can also use `forward_as_tuple` to get the best of both worlds between this and `tie`.

Comment: @StoryTeller How so? Doing `tup = std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2.0)` results in dangling references being stored.

Comment: @Danra - References can't rebind. Since `tup` holds references, it will simply do member wise assignment (to the referred to objects), with the value category of the sources preserved.

Comment: @StoryTeller While it's true references can't rebind, wouldn't the whole tuple's value just be reset as a whole? Since the type of `std::forward_as_tuple(1, 2.0)` exactly matches the type of `tup`, the assignment operator overload which just assigns the entire tuple would be chosen.

Comment: @Danra - It doesn't match exactly in this case, since `forward_as_tuple(1, 2.0)` creates a tuple of rvalue references. And even if it does, the copy assignment and move assignment operators of `std::tuple` operate member wise as well. `tup` will refer to the same objects, and they will be assigned to. It all works in a fairly sane manner, even though the rules that dictate the whole thing can drive one to insanity when reading them.

Comment: @StoryTeller Agree, this would, in theory, avoid unnecessary copies there and there but I think compiler would optimize the three expression the same way (`make_tuple`, `tie`, `forward_as_tuple`).

Comment: @Holt - Probably, maybe. I just wanted to add it for completeness :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Two problems:

1. You are trying to expand the pack in a context that is simply not allowed in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).
2. There should be only one pack expansion, for the entire assignment expression.

We can fix it by introducing a dummy array, whose initializer will supply the context for pack expansion:

```
int dummy[]{ ((void(std::get<Is>(dest) = values)), 0)... };
(void)dummy;
```

The [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) solution is a fold expression, naturally:

```
(void(std::get<Is>(dest) = values), ...);
```

Comment: Thanks so much as usual. Ugh, the workaround for the context thing is so ugly. It seems odd, how you must resort to fold expressions to get it to look (somewhat) better.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing a good example!

std::tie works perfectly for this:

```
template<class... Types>
void assign_values(std::tuple<Types&...>& dest, Types... values) {
    dest = std::tie(values...);
}

int main() {
  int a {};
  double b {};
  std::tuple<int&, double&> tup = {a, b};
  assign_values(tup, 1, 2.0);
  return a + b;
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/g/oU2Pi8 for proof.

Additional note: it's best to add some const safety, which will also prevent you from passing strings by value:

```
template<class... Types>
void assign_values(std::tuple<Types&...>& dest, const Types&... values) {
    dest = std::tie(values...);
}
```